# Comparing Spinner Values to Change textView

Tags: java, android

Have lots of old answers for this but none have assisted, have spent 2 weeks researching before putting this up. I have 2 spinners created via strings.xml, when the user selects an option from each spinner it will change the textView to a specific value e.g. 3. Below is what I have put together based on examples around the net, issues seems to be .equals and setText return a cannot resolve method errors.

Any assistance that can be provided is appreciated.

```
public class Main3Activity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
        Spinner spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        if (spinner.equals("Selection 1")&& spinner2.equals("Option 2"))
            textView8.setText("3");
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
}
```

IntelliJ answer which resolved my issues as per below.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    Spinner spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    TextView textView8=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView8);

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            if (spinner.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Selection 1")
                    && spinner2.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Option 2"))
            {
                textView8.setText("3");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });

}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add  **`getSelectedItem().toString()`**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    Spinner spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);

spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() 
     {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                       if (spinner.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Selection 1"))

                       {
                          textView8.setText("3");
                       }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                    }
                });

  spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() 
     {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                       if (spinner2.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Option 2"))
                       {
                          textView8.setText("3");
                       }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                    }
                });             

     }
```

Comment: Thanks IntelliJ. I have added as per your advice; this now brings back a cannot resolve method error for getSelectedItem and setText. This seems to be my stumbling block no matter which way I try to complete the if statement.

Comment: I copied yours directly across as per revised above

Comment: Thanks IntelliJ, that fixed the getSelectedItem errors but the setText cannot resolve method error remains. This is the one that always persists for the last 2 weeks I can't work out why it remains.

Comment: `TextView  textView8=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView8);`

Comment: @CraigDavison Like `Spinner` you must declare `Textview`

Comment: @CraigDavison Its my duty :) .Happy coding .Move ahead